# How can you find the correlation coefficient without joint distribution?

Tags: correlation, covariance

$Let X ∼ N(0, 1), Y := I_{X>1} − I_{X<−1}$

How can you determine the correlation coefficient of X and Y?

I've tried to first calculate $COV[X, Y] = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]$, but since $E[X] = 0$, $COV[X, Y] = E[XY]$, however this still does seem to require the joint distribution which I'm not sure how to recover from the given information.

Comment: What does I{X>1} mean? Can you type up your question using $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: Hi, its the indicator function

Comment: Hint: You have clearly specified the joint distribution and $E[XY]$ is a straightforward integral--it requires no calculation and is simply expressible in terms of the standard Normal CDF.